# Problem applying Jquery UI theme to buttons

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to apply a theme to my  buttons (input type="button", input type="submit" and button) , but I haven't been able to get it to work, at least not in all of them, just in one, the   "Add" button. According to [this page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/), the only markup  I need  to apply a theme to a button , is simply this  `<button>Button Label</button>`. , but it just doesn't work.

I added a working demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edaloicaro18/7ZQDk/27/)

I really hope you can help me out with this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to apply the `button()` function for each `<button>` or `<input>` that you want styled as a button.  You could add the following to your code:

```
$("button, input:submit, input:button").button();
```

Which would apply the jQueryUI button styles to all `button` elements and `input` elements of type `button` or `submit`.

I updated your example: http://jsfiddle.net/hjYyb/

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew, but now I have a new problem :(, the "Save" button is initially disabled (disabled="true") , and  when I enable it using this :  $("#save").attr('disabled',false); it works , but the style doesn't change, I mean the button still looks as it was disabled http://jsfiddle.net/edaloicaro18/hjYyb/3/

Comment: @eddy: Try using `$("input:submit").button("enable")`.  This will use the jQueryUI API to enable the button.